# Is 90+ Conjuration required for the Sigil Stone quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Do you need 90+ Conjuration to do the Sigil Stone quest or can you cheat and still do it?

Comment: I fixed your question this time, but next time, please put some effort into writing your question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [wikia page for the Sigil Stone](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sigil_Stone_(Skyrim)), it looks like you need at least 90 Conjuration to unlock this quest. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by cheat, but if you mean boost yourself to 90 Conjuration with console commands, that shouldn't matter in unlocking the quest.

> To obtain a sigil stone, the Dragonborn (**after reaching a Conjuration level of 90 or higher**) must seek out Phinis Gestor, an Expert Conjurer of the College of Winterhold.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Comment: I think what he meant by cheat is to used Console Commands. (I think he uses PC)

Comment: @JimJones that was my assumption as well

Comment: No I meant by using the do not delete chests @vemonus

Comment: @Dovakhiin could you edit that into your question?